# static initialization and smart pointers

Tags: c++

Is this function guaranteed not to create any memory leaks (there is no additional allocation in `SomeObject`):

```
void FreeFunction()
{
   static boost::scoped_ptr<SomeObject> MyStaticObject(new SomeObject);
}
```

I never used the combination of static allocation and a smart pointer. It seems to work fine with my compiler, but I would like to know if this always cleans up the allocated memory.

Comment: Do you have a reason for not using `static SomeObject MyStaticObject;`? What do you gain by using dynamic allocation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is no memory leak.
The `static` here means that the variable `MyStaticObject` is initialized on first call to `FreeFunction()` and then it stays alive throughout the lifetime of the program(just like any other static variable would).
The C++ run-time arranges and makes sure that `MyStaticObject` is destroyed at some point.